# Working with multi-page images in an NSImage

Tags: objective-c, tiff, nsimage

I'm working on an image viewer application (OSX) and currently it can load and view images, but I need to be able to view multi-page PDFs and TIFFs. I'll have next/previous page buttons, etc.

Now, with PDF, I expect to use an NSPDFImageRep. This will let me set the current page and draw the current page etc.

However, I don't see an NSTIFFImageRep, and the NSImageRep class doesn't seem to have any way of dealing with pages...

ETA (more specifics on my question): How do I work with a multi-page TIFF? In C, I used a CGImageSource which let me get the nth page. I don't see an equivalent for TIFFs in objective C.

thanks.

Comment: What is your actual question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would expect that the easiest thing for you to do for a mixed PDF and TIFF viewer would be to make each non-PDF page a unique NSImageRep.

Comment: But how do I get the individual pages out of the TIFF file?
If I can get the nth page in a multi-page TIFF, then I can do the rest...

Comment: AH! Now I see. each page is a separate representation. that seems like an unfortunate use of the concept, but seems to work well enough.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not positive, but IIRC if you initialize an NSImage with multi-page TIFF data, you will get one image rep per page. (Probably what peterb was alluding to.)

Edit: Check out [+[NSBitmapImageRep imageRepsWithData:]](http://developer.apple.com/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/ApplicationKit/Classes/nsbitmapimagerep_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/clm/NSBitmapImageRep/imageRepsWithData:).

(via [Apple Lists](http://lists.apple.com/archives/cocoa-dev//2002/Mar/msg00557.html))

Comment: I'll look into the ...withdata method. But if I just do an initWithFile on a TIFF file, I just get an NSImage of the 1st page...

Comment: Try iterating through the array returned by -[NSImage representations]. An NSImage will only draw one of its representations if you ask it to draw directly!